# Adobe Illustrator formating to JPG turing out stretchy @

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, png, jpg, compression

I have finished some work on Adobe Illustrator, converted it to PDF and then JPG. but no matter how many times I changed the settings with compression,
My art board looks all squished...anybody know how to solve this?

I am trying to use the image on Word Press for my website. Haven't really had this issue before and I am using the "web" option artboard when opening my AI.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid "looks all squished" isn't really a lot to go on. If dimensions are changing, then there's some setting somewhere causing them to change. Without more detailed steps, I think it's impossible to really help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to export a pdf and then open it in an unknown program to do some shadowy conversion to jpg...

On Illustrator use the "Export for web" dialog box.

Use pixels as your unit. If it is some flat design use PNG, not JPG.